# Knex filter on pre filtered request

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I would like to achieve a request in which I can filter my results with `where` clauses and then apply others `where` but on the result of the first `where`

```
    return await UserModel.query()
        .withGraphFetched('roles')

        .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
            if (accessControlFilters.agency_id) {
                queryBuilder.orWhere('agency_id', accessControlFilters.agency_id)
            }
            if (accessControlFilters.third_party.length) {
                queryBuilder.orWhereIn('third_party_id', accessControlFilters.third_party)
            }
            if (accessControlFilters.corporation.length) {
                queryBuilder.orWhereIn('corporation_id', accessControlFilters.corporation) 
            }
        })
        .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
            if (Array.isArray(userFilters.corporation) && userFilters.corporation.length) {
                queryBuilder.orWhereIn('corporation_id', userFilters.corporation)
            }
            if (Array.isArray(userFilters.third_party) && userFilters.third_party.length) {
                queryBuilder.orWhereIn('third_party_id', userFilters.third_party)
            }
        })
        .limit(limit)
        .offset(offset)
        .debug()
```

But there it just concatenates my first modifier with the second :(
DO you have any clue how i can achieve this ?

Comment: what scenario is playing out for you that you are trying to achieve it in two separate queries? 

chaining where clauses and modify is doing just that, you can do raw statements in the modify if you have specific queries, if the resulted rows are too small then you can filter them in javascript

Comment: In fact, I have filters about access control + the one provided by the user.
And what I did try to achieve was to first filter with access control and then, inside this primary filter, apply the user filters. But that not the right way to do it. I will check user filters and merge them with the access control filters.

Comment: your access control should be its own middleware, separate your concerns so you don't have hard time debugging later on